# Getting PNG binary data from GDALDataset

Tags: gdal, c++, in-memory

I have an in memory GDALDataset of driver type PNG. How can I get the binary PNG data to send to a web client without first writing the GDALDataset PNG to disk and reading it back as a binary file?

Comment: Is the in-memory PNG in "`/vsimem`"?

Comment: Look at `VSIStatExL`/`VSIStatL` (with `VSI_STAT_SIZE_FLAG` to get file size), `VSIFOpenExL`/`VSIFOpenL` and `VSIFReadL`

Comment: Thanks you sooo much! With your pointers I was able to figure this out. If you'd like to post your comments as an answer with a little more details I will mark it as such... otherwise I'll post my solution as the answer tomorrow.

Comment: actually using it from nodejs (typescript) using the node-gdal bindings, but that doesn't matter since I'm doing all the work in some custom c++ and just returning a buffer to node.

Comment: I can only answer using Python, so go ahead and post your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it in Python (the python bindings are pretty similar to the C++ library so should be simples to port) using the `VSIStatL` (with `VSI_STAT_SIZE_FLAG` to get file size), `VSIFOpenL` and `VSIFReadL` [methods](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VSIFOpenL):

```py
from osgeo import gdal

vsipath = "/vsimem/test.png"

# Read the file from disk just for demo purposes, 
# membuf could be read from a socket, url, etc.
pngpath = r"/path/to/test.png"
membuf = open(pngpath, 'rb').read()

# Write to in-memory file and open as a GDALDataset
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vsipath, membuf)
memds = gdal.OpenEx(vsipath)

# Do whatever processing, i.e. gdal.Warp etc.

# Read the VSIFile (pretend vsipath and memds now refer to in-memory file
# and GDALDataset produced by gdal.Warp etc)
stat = gdal.VSIStatL(vsipath, gdal.VSI_STAT_SIZE_FLAG)
vsifile = gdal.VSIFOpenL(vsipath, 'r')  # could also use memds.GetDescription() instead of vsipath var
vsibuf = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, stat.size, vsifile)

# just for demo purposes, show that what we just read is the same as what we originally had
assert vsibuf == membuf
```